# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing

I'm getting a ''Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException'' in my code. I have no idea why and where this exception occurs. The compilation works fine but sometimes I get this error at runtime. Can I have some help here? The full error message is this:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2115)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

part of my code:

```
class UserAgentGui extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener, CinemaVocabulary {

private JTable movieTable;

public UserAgentGui(UserAgent a) {
// -----------------------------------   Constructor

    Object obj[][] = new Object[0][columnNames.length];
    TableModel model = new TableDataModel(obj, columnNames);
    movieTable = new JTable(model);
movieTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    movieTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(320,100));
    movieTable.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
}

void displayMovies(java.util.leap.List list) {
// -------------------------------------------
    String s = "";

    if (menu.getSelectedItem().equals(actions[1])){//  <-- This is a list of movies
        s = "Movie-databse is presented";
        data = new Object[list.size()][columnNames.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Movie movie = (Movie)list.get(i);
            data[i][0] = movie.getTitle();
            data[i][1] = movie.getYear();
            data[i][2] = movie.getKind();
            data[i][3] = 0.0;
        }
    TableDataModel model = (TableDataModel)movieTable.getModel();
    model.setData(data);
    movieTable.setModel(model);
    movieTable.updateUI();
    }
    else {
        s = "Score Movies";
    }
    msg_text.setText(s);    
}

// =========================== External class ============================//

/* TableDataModel:
*  --------------
*  External class for the definition of the tables data model, used to
*  control the display of data within the different tables
**/
class TableDataModel extends AbstractTableModel {
// ----------------------------------------------

   private String[] columns;
   private Object[][] data;

   public TableDataModel(Object[][] data, String[] columns) {
   // ----------------------------------------------------------  Constructor
      this.data = data;
      this.columns = columns;
   }

   public int getColumnCount() {
   // -----------------------------  Return the number of columns in the table
      return columns.length;
   }

   public int getRowCount() {
   // --------------------------  Return the number of rows in the table
      return data.length;
   }

   public String getColumnName(int col) {
   // --------------------------------------  Return the name of a column
      return columns[col];
   }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
   // -------------------------------------------------
            if (col == 3) {
                return true;
           } else {
               return false;
            }
   }

   public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
   // --------------------------------------------  Return the value at a specific
//                                               row and column
      if ( data.length == 0 ) return null;
         return data[row][col];
    }

   public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
   // --------------------------------------  Return the class of the values held
   //                                         by a column
      Object o = getValueAt(0, col);
      if (o == null) return columns[col].getClass();
         return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
   } 

   public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
    // -------------------------------------------------------  Set the value at a        specific
   //                                                          row and column
      data[row][col] = value;
  }

   public void setData(Object[][] data){
   // -------------------------------------  Update the entire data in the table
       this.data = data;
   }

   Object[][] getData(){
   // ---------------------  Return the entire data of the table
       return data;
   }
}// end TableDataModel
}
```

Comment: My wild guess is that you are using the JTable variable without instantiating  it .Show your code..

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Could You post your code?

Comment: What's that: `movieTable.updateUI();` ? although it should be harmless, it is not meant to be used directly (unless you specifically change the L&F)

Answer (score 2):

`Object obj[][] = new Object[0][columnNames.length];`
You have set the 1st Dimensional size of obj as 0.
It should be `Object obj[][]= new Object[1][columnNames.length]`

Comment: +1 only one pct from issues :-)

Comment: lol..yeah..bit exhausted....;)

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the Stack Trace it is trying to draw your screen contents. Perhaps something is not initialized correctly on that screen or one of its components.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting a ''Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException'' in my code. I have no idea why and
>   where this exception occurs. The compilation works fine but sometimes
>   I get this error at runtime. Can I have some help here? The full error
>   message is this:

- this question isn't answerable at all, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, required to hardcode all custom classes to the local variable
- you mixing two XxxTableModels, no reason why to take TableDataModel model from TableModel
- TableModel is un_know from this code
- TableDataModel isn't added to visible JTable,
- void displayMovies(java.util.leap.List list) { isn't standard java import
- movieTable.updateUI(); will be works in the case that you'll creates own BasicTableUI, but this part hasn't something with XxxTableModel and code post here,
- updateUI() is methods for UIManager and Look And Feel, not for displaying data from shared model to the screen